# PHP echo error array out of function

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array called $messages, and I want to output messages through the array within different functions.

```
function validateNumber($number) {

    if(!is_numeric($number)) {
       $messages[] = 'This aint a number bro';
       return $messages;
    }

}
```

On my view i have

```
foreach($messages as $message) {
   echo $message;
 }
```

Why is this not working? I want to it to echo out the message on the foreach I have.

Comment: You're missing the part where you get the returned values: `$messages = validateNumber($number);`

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the messages you need to return it because `$messages` is only available inside your `validateNumber` function.

```
$messages = validateNumber($number);
foreach($messages as $message) {
   echo $message;
}
```

---

If `validateNumber` only contains this one if clause it does not really make sense to add the message to an array. You can simply return it as a string and use the result:

```
function validateNumber($number) {
    if(!is_numeric($number)) {
       $message = 'This aint a number bro';

       return $message;
    }
}
```

You call it the same way:

```
$message = validateNumber($number);
```